# Tar: Directory Checksum Error

Tags: shell, unix, backup, tar

I am writing to a HP LTO4 tape drive. But after writing a big file (of the order 30GB) I am not able to write anything after that. I get

```
    tar: directory checksum error
```

Anyone has any idea what could be wrong?

I am using the command

```
tar -rvfE /dev/rmt/0 <file.gz>
```

Need help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem resolved by using -i flag. 
So now I am using the command

```
tar -rvfEi /dev/rmt/0 <file>
```

:)